# Activate a worksheet to a specific section

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I would like to activate a worksheet so that it always open's looking at specific cells.

The worksheet I have has some other bits out of view that the user doesn't need to see, so I wanted to make sure when the sheet activated it shows the area that the user needs to interact with.

If you need anymore calrification please ask.Thank you

Comment: From a design point of view, why not have a hidden worksheet containing the data you don't want the user to see?

Comment: I am just editing something made by another person so i cant change all the baseline stuff he has done i just wanted to make it a bit more user friendly. But i will keep that in mind for my own projects, thank you.

Comment: can you just hide the columns you don't want users to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an event within the sheet in question would cause some code to run each time the sheet is activated like so:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Me.Cells(4, 6).Activate
End Sub
```

In this case, the cell `F4` (4th row, 6th column) would be activated - but you can adjust this as you need.